# How to update Google Play Services repo to last version in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I have installed the latest final version 2.3.3 of Android Studio, and it says that no updates found. 
I see on [Play Services website](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) that the latest version is 11.4.0 from September 2017.
But on my system I see in path `Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services` that I have latest 11.0.4 from June 2017.
And Android Studio in settings says that Google Play Services is installed and have no updates, revision is 45.
How to update it to the latest version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They now use their own maven repo instead of the local repos, 
add it to your top level `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Did they announced this somewhere?

Comment: Yes, The most recent versions of the following Android libraries are available from Google's Maven repository. Go through this source https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven